# how to open different view controllers on app launch in iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have two views - view1 and view2. 
View1 is my default viewcontroller loaded from mainwindow.xib.
Depending on some condition checking, i want to load either View1 or View2, say if user registration is not done, load sign up screen for user, else go to default view controller.

How and where do I check this condition?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just planning on bringing up a sign-up screen if the user registration is needed, why not stick with the default view controller, but at `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` present a modal view controller for the sign up view?

Answer (score 3):

In your app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {
     if(needToLogin) {
         [self setViewController:[[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNib:@"Login View"] autorelease]];

     }

     [window setRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

This will switch your view controller to the view2 view controller if needToLogin returns true. Otherwise, it will go to the default controller specified in mainwindow.xib

Another method (since you probably need the main view controller anyway) would be to present the login view controller if its needed.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions  {
     if(needToLogin) {
         ViewController2 *loginVC = [[[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNib:@"LoginViewController"] autorelease];

         [[self viewController] presentViewController:loginVC animated:NO];
     }

     [window setRootViewController:viewController];
}
```

Note, you will have to call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES]` to get rid of the login view.

**Edit:** Respones from OP:

I tried first one,

```
if(loginflag){ 
     [self setViewController:[[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]]; 
} 

[self.window setRootViewController:self.signUpView];
```

Try this instead:

```
if(loginFlag) {
     [self setViewController:[[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
}

[[self window] setRootViewController:[self viewController]];
```

Comment: I tried first one, if(loginflag){
        
       
            [self setViewController:[[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
        
    }
    
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.signUpView];
    }

Comment: instead of `[[self window] setRootViewController:[self signUpView]];` do `[[self window] setRootViewController:[self viewController]]`

Comment: not working stillNSString *str = [standardUserDefaults valueForKey:@"REGISTEREDUSER"];
        
        NSLog(@"STR IS > %@", str);
        
        if([str isEqualToString:@""] || [str isEqual:nil] ){
          
                [self setViewController:[[[SignUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SignUpViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease]];
        }
            
            [[self window] setRootViewController:[self viewController]];
    }

Comment: is it getting inside that if statement? Put a breakpoint or an NSLog

Comment: No, its not going into didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, i have put a breakpoint over there. :( Still stuck with this issue...please help

Comment: If it isnt getting into the `if` statement, then there is a problem with your `loginFlag`. If it isn't going into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` at all, then it didn't finish launching and you have a different problem.

Comment: yeah, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not getting called, so the code above is not executing .. What needs to be done in this case? Please help

Comment: Double-Click on MainWindow.xib then select ‘File’s Owner’, then go to:
Tools > Connections Inspector
Under outlets you will see ‘Delegate’ drag from the circle next to it to your “APP_NAME App Delegate” icon, save and try again…

Answer (score 0):

With the information given, you could just create a flag in the AppDelegate that can be persisted based on the user registration is complete or not.  Then in the "didFinishLaunching..." method you could check this flag and load the the proper view based on this.